# React router clicks on the same link

Tags: hyperlink, react-router

I have using react-router for my project. where i click on a link that render by  component multiple times. it push multiples link that the same path to the History. So how can i prevent it. Thank!

Comment: Could you be more precise? I don't understand what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

It was bug in [history](https://github.com/rackt/history) package that `react-router` use. 
According to [this](https://github.com/rackt/history/issues/105) issue they released fix in version **1.13.1**.
So everything you need is upgrade your `history` package